# Replacement RSS reader for Mountain Lion, integrated with Notification Center?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, rss

I am looking for a recommendation for a replacement RSS reader for Mountain Lion. I have used RSS feeds in Mail.app for semi-important alerts, like maintenance announcements from my webhost or new posts on rarely updated blogs. I do not want or need a full dedicated "news reader". Occasional messages in my inbox were perfect.

Is there a good, inexpensive RSS reader that I do not have to check separately but that keeps me up-to-date with these kind of occasional RSS updates? Preferably integrated into Notification Center, which would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, in order to integrate into Notification Centre, an app needs to have been purchased from the App Store.  Only App Store apps can use it (same with most iCloud features).  So your search needs to start there.

2 very popular RSS readers are Reeder and NewsNetWire.  Neither have been update to use Notification Centre yet so far as I know, but for sure some of them will be.

It's likely that if you can find an RSS reader that used to use Growl as it's notification method, then it will be modified in time to use Notification Centre instead, but there are so many RSS readers (particularly on iOS, perhaps less so on the Mac App Store) that I can't name a particular app right now.

I quick search for "rss notification" yields no results, but "rss growl" gives 3 hits (Note that for those who are not aware, Growl is in effect a third party tool that has done what Notification Centre will do for years already, and loads of apps already support it):

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/cappuccino/id492594411?mt=12

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/monotony/id533978766?mt=12

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/feeds/id458374415?mt=12

The fact that these 3 already support some form of notifications *may* be indicative they they will be amogst the first to support OS X 10.8 Notification Centre.

However there is another way:

For those apps (not just RSS) that use Growl, there is talk that Growl will morph into a sort of bridge between the Notification Centre and non MAS apps, because it is on the MAS itself, and as such can install notifications into the tray, and it can also poll other apps for Growl notifications and simply pass them on without the originating app needing to know about Notification Centre formally.  See [this](http://growl.posterous.com/going-forward-with-growl-and-notification-cen) blog post for info.

It's not happened yet tho, although there is already an app to bridge between Growl and Notification Centre called HISS (See here http://9to5mac.com/2012/07/25/put-growl-in-your-notification-center-with-hiss/) which will punt any grown notification into NC instead, although it's very much Beta, and frankly will be superceded as soon as Growl get their own act together, but at least it is available *now*.

As such you may be able to roll your own temporary bodge using a combination of an RSS reader as suggested above that supports Growl, installing and using Growl, installing Hiss to pass Growl notifications into the Notification Centre...

Comment: Obviously, you don't need an app from the App Store, if HISS can do it. That said, you still need app support for the Notification Center, which will probably appear in more apps soon.

Comment: This is unclear, when announced it was stated that only MAS apps would have NC available to them.  See the first reaction from the Grown Devs here (http://growl.posterous.com/growls-response-to-notification-center-welcom) "Our understanding from press reports at this point is that Notification Center is only available to apps from the Mac App Store", and I'm not 100% sure if that simply isn't true any more, or if HISS only works with the MAS version of Growl.  Either way, if your app support Growl, then soon it will also support NC properly without needing an update. HISS is a temp' bodge fix.

Comment: Thanks. Monotony actually looks very promising. The auther [states](http://www.timschroeder.net/software/monotony/) he's going to work on NC integration over the weekend, and otherwise it does exactly what I want.

Comment: BTW, *local notifications* are perfectly possible through a local API and do not require the app to go through the App Store. Only iCloud notification require this.

Comment: Ah, that's probably where the confusion lies.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Caffeinated is the only rss app I know of that uses notification center.

Answer (score 1):

[RSS.app](http://www.rssapplication.com) is a free lightweight RSS reader which integrates with Notification Center.

Answer (score 1):

Try [LuckNews](https://itunes.apple.com/app/lucknews/id590365026?ls=1&mt=12) - its free and also does not use the Google Reader API which Google has announced will be going away in July.  It supports Notifications and much more.